# Adding a column to a data frame

Tags: r

So, I have a data frame and I want to add a column to it at the `first` position. Right now it gets added at the end. Also rearranging the data frame by column name is not desired since I have around 1000 columns. Is there a quick way by which I can do this?

Comment: Perhaps, `as.data.frame(cbind(column,df))`?

Comment: `data.frame(newcol=column, origdf)` may be safer

Comment: `as.data.frame(cbind())` is a poor solution as it will coerce the entire `data.frame` to the same mode.